# AngularJS autologin before page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile

I try to implement a remember-login function to my AngularJS / ionic mobile app

**the problem:**
the login page is allways loaded before the automatic login is finished and the transition starts, so you can see the login page for a moment.

**question:**
is there an event like 'pagebeforeshow' in JQM or another method to directly load the 'home' state?

**I use:**
ionic 1.3.1
angular 1.5.3
cordova 4.0.0

**code examples:**
LoginController:

```
function LoginController($scope, $http, $ionicModal, $state, $SessionStorage) {
    var vm = this;
    activate();

    function activate(){
        vm.staylogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.staylogged || null);
        if(vm.staylogged){
            vm.remember = vm.staylogged; //vm.remember: checkbox in login form
            login();
        }else{
            // get some data from the server
        }
    }

    function login(){
        if(vm.staylogged){
            //get login informations from localStorage
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: vm.server +"?=GetLogin",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"'
            },
            data: soa
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(response.returnCode == 0){
                localStorage.setItem('staylogged', JSON.stringify(vm.remember));
                // safe login informations to local Storage for next use
                $state.go('tabs.home');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look into using the resolve available in the ui-router library

Answer (score 0):

You can do following way -

In app.js

```
.state('signin', {
       url: '/sign-in',
       templateUrl: 'templates/views/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginController',
       resolve: {
               // Do your code here will execute before page render
       }
})
```

Comment: i tried the resolve, but it seems you can't change the state at this moment, because the current state is still initialising... should I use something like the "timeout"-stage-change or is there another possibiliti to decide which state should be loaded?